# How to give current time has default

Tags: django

in models i have a DateTime field. but in my template i have separate Date and Time for the user to enter. how do i give current time as default.

```
Models.py

 datetime_reading=models.DateTimeField()

truepower_reading=models.DecimalField(verbose_name="True Power Reading(KWH)",max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
apparentpower_reading=models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Apparent Power Reading(KVAH)",max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
truepower_consumed=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
voltage_reading=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
powerfactor=models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=2)




 Forms.py

Date=forms.DateField()
Time=forms.TimeField()
fields = ('date', 'time', 'truepower_reading', 'apparentpower_reading',"voltage_reading")
class Meta:
    model=KEBReading
    exclude=("truepower_consumed","powerfactor","datetime_reading")
    widgets = {

               "date" : forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%d/%m/%Y"),
               "time" : forms.widgets.TimeInput(format="%H:%M")
               }


 views.py
 def KEBReading1(request):
q2=KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('datetime_reading')[:30]

form = KEBReading_form()
monthform=MonthForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('KEBsubmit'):
        form = KEBReading_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("datetime_reading")                   
                date=form.cleaned_data["Date"]
                print type(date)

                time=form.cleaned_data["Time"]
                print type(time)

                kr_truepower_reading = form.cleaned_data["truepower_reading"]
                kr_apparentpower_reading = form.cleaned_data["apparentpower_reading"]

                truepower_consumed1=kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading
                powerfactor1=((kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading)/(kr_apparentpower_reading-prevdate.apparentpower_reading))     
                form1=form.save(commit=False)
                print "tee"
                form1.datetime_reading=datetime.combine(date,time)
                print form1.datetime_reading



                form1.truepower_consumed=truepower_consumed1
                form1.powerfactor=powerfactor1

                print form1.powerfactor


                form1.save()
```

this is my view codes. i m trying to get the entered time from the forms. but do i give the current time for the user to enter.

```
views.py


q2=KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('datetime_reading')[:30]

form = KEBReading_form()
monthform=MonthForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('KEBsubmit'):
        form = KEBReading_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("datetime_reading")    
                time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I")
                data = {'Time':time}
                form = KEBReading_form(data)     


                date=form.cleaned_data["Date"]
                print type(date)

                time=form.cleaned_data["Time"]
                print type(time)

                kr_truepower_reading = form.cleaned_data["truepower_reading"]
                kr_apparentpower_reading = form.cleaned_data["apparentpower_reading"]
```

i gave it in the views as mentioned above. do i have to specify sumthin in forms as well???

i want the hour,minute and secoond. is this right

```
form = KEBReading_form()
time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
time=time1.hour,time1.minute,time1.second

data = {'Time':time}
print data
form = KEBReading_form(data)
```

Comment: how will it populate the current time to the specified field in the form. dont v have to specify?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) describes setting initial values in forms.

**views.py**

```
def view_name(request):    
    q2=KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('datetime_reading')[:30]
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M")
    data = {'Time':time}
    form = KEBReading_form(data)
    monthform=MonthForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        ...........

    return render(request, 'page.html', {'form':form,})
```

Comment: I updated your answer with a link to the documentation, hope you don't mind.